# Merge service in Dynamics 365 C# plugin erroring out

Tags: c#, merge, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I am attempting to `merge` contact records in CRM.  The following is my code and works fine until the end line at `var merged = (MergeResponse)service.Execute(merge);`  I have tracers in the original code and is definitely erroring out at that specific line.

```
// Create the target for the request.
var target = new EntityReference();

// Id is the GUID of the account that is being merged into.
// LogicalName is the type of the entity being merged to, as a string
var targetId = (Guid)master.Attributes["contactid"];
target.LogicalName = entity.LogicalName;

// Create the request.
var merge = new MergeRequest();

// SubordinateId is the GUID of the account merging.
merge.SubordinateId = (Guid)subordinates.Attributes["contactid"];
merge.Target = target;
merge.PerformParentingChecks = false;
tracer.Trace("\nMerging contact2 into contact1 and adding " + "\"test job title from plugin\" as job title");

// Create another contact to hold new data to merge into the entity.
// If you use the subordinate account object, its data will be merged.

var updateContent = new Entity();
updateContent.LogicalName = entity.LogicalName;
updateContent["jobtitle"] = "test job title from plugin";

// Set the content you want updated on the merged account
merge.UpdateContent = updateContent;
// Execute the request.
var merged = (MergeResponse)service.Execute(merge);
```

The following is the error:

> Exception type:
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]
> Message: An error occurred in TransformaniaMergeContactsPlugin.Detail:
>
> 421301f5-3f26-4eb9-a546-88a93ff52f33
> -2147220891   d2p1:keyOperationStatus</d2p1:key>
> <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:int">0</d2p1:value> 
>  d2p1:keySubErrorCode</d2p1:key>
> <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:int">-2146233088</d2p1:value>
>  
> d2p1:keyPlugin.ExceptionFromPluginExecute</d2p1:key> <d2p1:value
> xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:string">Transormania.Plugins.TransformaniaMergeContactsPlugin</d2p1:value>
>  
> d2p1:keyPlugin.ExceptionRetriable</d2p1:key> <d2p1:value
> xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:boolean">false</d2p1:value>
>  
> d2p1:keyPlugin.ExceptionSource</d2p1:key> <d2p1:value
> xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:string">PluginExecution</d2p1:value>
>  
> d2p1:keyPlugin.OriginalException</d2p1:key> <d2p1:value
> xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:string">PluginExecution</d2p1:value>
>  
> d2p1:keyPlugin.PluginTrace</d2p1:key> <d2p1:value
> xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> i:type="d4p1:string">Hello plugin In Master entity for each results
> Master: test | contact | 2325a10e-527e-e911-a81d-000d3a1d9cdc | Group
> ID: 00000001 Subordinate: Test | User |
> b01d0639-847d-e911-a81a-000d3a1f0599 | Group ID: 00000001 Master Guid:
> 2325a10e-527e-e911-a81d-000d3a1d9cdc Entity Logical Name: contact
> Subordinate Id: b01d0639-847d-e911-a81a-000d3a1f0599
>
> Merging contact2 into contact1 and adding "test job title from plugin"
> as job title Before update content Merge Content:
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity</d2p1:value> 
>   An error occurred
> in TransformaniaMergeContactsPlugin.
> 2021-12-09T18:49:10.8671998Z
> false
> PluginExecution  PluginExecution
>  Hello plugin In Master entity for each results Master:
> test | contact | 2325a10e-527e-e911-a81d-000d3a1d9cdc | Group ID:
> 00000001 Subordinate: Test | User |
> b01d0639-847d-e911-a81a-000d3a1f0599 | Group ID: 00000001 Master Guid:
> 2325a10e-527e-e911-a81d-000d3a1d9cdc Entity Logical Name: contact
> Subordinate Id: b01d0639-847d-e911-a81a-000d3a1f0599
>
> Merging contact2 into contact1 and adding "test job title from plugin"
> as job title Before update content Merge Content:
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity

I'm not seeing anything specific to what the error is and am running out of options. Any extra eyes will help.

Comment: The error code hints at this: `Name: HybridSSSExchangeOnlineS2SCertActsExpired, Hex: 80131500, Number: -2146233088`. Does this ring a bell? Your error log is not very helpful.  For debugging purposes an extensive log will prove to be very valuable. Add as much contextual information as possible: input parameters, pre/post images etc. As an alternative you could try executing the code in a console app/Visual Studio.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I did a search of the error code as well and did see the same result as you. Doesn't ring a bell and I don't think it has to do with the actual error.  I think the error is being produced when the code is trying to merge an "inactive" record. I did some tests and the merge request is intermittently working.

Comment: Attempting to merge "inactive" records was definitely the issue.  Do I close this question or leave open and answer it?

Comment: An answer seems to me to be helpful.